# Setting values based upon whether the host ID exists in a list

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, salt-stack

I am trying to create a state where a handful of settings can be retrieved without me having to make lots of individual pillar files for all the hosts. This way seems tedious and incorrect but I can't wrap my head around how to do it with Jinja and YAML.

How I was doing it:

/srv/pillar
hosts1.sls,host2.sls,host3.sls,...host1000

```
cluster:
  name: cluster_one
  server: 1.1.1.1
  setting: foo
```

/srv/pillar
hosts4.sls,host5.sls,host6.sls,...

```
cluster:
  name: cluster_two
  server: 2.2.2.2
  setting: bar
```

Is it possible to do something like this with pillar or even a map.jinja file and then use Jinja to in a state file and say 'if my minion name is in the members list, then set these server, setting and cluster name'?

```
clusters:
  cluster_one:
    server: 1.1.1.1
    setting: foo
    members:
       - host1
       - host2
       - host3
  cluster_two
    server: 2.2.2.2
    setting: bar
    members:
      - host4
      - host5
      - host6
```

The end result I wanted is just those three lines in a file like this.

host1,host2,host3
/tmp/example.txt

```
name: cluster_one
server: 1.1.1.1
setting: foo
```

host4,host5,host6
/tmp/example.txt

```
name: cluster_two
server: 2.2.2.2
setting: bar
```

The idea being that I want to just be able add minions to the members list without then having to make tons of new pillar files for each host. A host would only appear in one cluster so no need to worry about matching.

Then if I wanted to add new members I could simple edit this (refresh if needed) and apply without having to create new pillar files for host7, host8, and host9.

```
clusters:
  cluster_one:
    server: 1.1.1.1
    setting: foo
    members:
       - host1
       - host2
       - host3
  cluster_two
    server: 2.2.2.2
    setting: bar
    members:
      - host4
      - host5
      - host6
 cluster_three
   server: 3.3.3.3
   setting: baz
   members:
     - host7
     - host8
     - host9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve this with by organizing the pillar data and using Jinja template to create the resulting file on minions.

**Pillar**

Consider the pillar data `pillar/data.sls`:

```yaml
clusters:
  - name: cluster_one
    server: 1.1.1.1
    setting: foo
    members:
      - host1
      - host2
      - host3
  - name: cluster_two
    server: 2.2.2.2
    setting: bar
    members:
      - host4
      - host5
      - host6
  - name: cluster_three
    server: 3.3.3.3
    setting: baz
    members:
      - host7
      - host8
      - host9
```

**Jinja Template**

Then have a template for `test/example.txt.j2` as below:

```
{%- for cluster in clusters -%}
{%- if grains['id'] in cluster.members -%}
name: {{ cluster.name }}
server: {{ cluster.server }}
setting: {{ cluster.setting }}
{%- endif -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```

**State SLS**

Then I have a simple `file.managed` in `test.sls` to render the above template:

```yaml
create_temp_file:
  file.managed:
    - name: /tmp/example.txt
    - source: salt://test/example.txt.j2
    - mode: 0644
    - template: jinja
    - defaults:
        clusters: {{ pillar['clusters'] }}
```

Comment: Thank you for this!